# Modification of Windows Registry via .REG file - copy and delete

Tags: windows, regedit

I have this text in `.reg` file:

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\program]

 "item2"=item1
 "item3"=item1
```

In registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\program]` there is a value `item1`. I want to put data of this value into another value `item2` and `item3` but the code that I tried does not work.

Furthermore how can I delete a registry value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any reference of how to copy registry keys by means of `.reg` files. Anyway it can be done from command line (or batch script) by following command. ([MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742057.aspx))

```
REG COPY <SourceKeyName> <DestinationKeyName> [/s] [/f]
```

In your case it is:

```
REG COPY HKCU\Software\program\item1 HKCU\Software\program\item0
```

To delete keys/values (by means of `.reg` file) use this. ([MS Support](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/310516))

```
; for key
[-HKCU\Software\program\item10]

; for value
[HKCU\Software\program\item10]
"TestValue"=-
```